# string automatically converts const char* to std::string

Tags: c++, string

I stumbled upon this by receiving an "no instance for constructor" error when using `std::out_of_range constructor` code with older compilers

For some older compilers the definition of `std::out_of_range` is

```
class out_of_range : public logic_error {
public:
      out_of_range(const string& message);
};
```

in more recent versions they've added a second constructor

```
class out_of_range : public logic_error {
public:
      out_of_range(const string& message);
      out_of_range(const char *message);
};
```

The code I was trying to compile did the following constructor call:

```
std::out_of_range("Some Error Message");
```

after adding `#include <string>`

The compiler was able to convert `const char*` to `std::string` ?

Is that the expected behavior?

Comment: It's the same reason you can do e.g. `std::string str = "foobar";` See e.g. [this `std::string` constructor reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) for more information (it's the constructor marked `5` in the list you should look at).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's expected, because the relevant constructor `std::string::string(const char*)` is **not** `explicit`, which means it's available for *implicit* conversions like this.

Comment: Plus, even though it's trying to capture a reference `const string&`, it is also allowed for the compiler to create a temporary and pass it as a reference at call time.